# Python,appending item to the list not working

Tags: python, loops, append, logic

I have this following variables all of them has it own use

```
attributes = {
     "base" : None,
     "recognize" : None,
     "type" : None,
     "is_correct" : False,
     "index" : 0
};
res = [];
tmp_que = [];
first_res = None;
```

then i have this parent loop

```
y = [["- a", "+ b"]]

for per in y :
    B.check(list(per));
    pass;
```

where B.check has this loop

```
 for index,per in enumerate(base):

            no_s_characters = ''.join(e for e in per if e.isalnum());
            first_char = str(per)[0] if len(no_s_characters) > 0 else None;
            is_empty_que = len(res) <= 0;

            params = attributes;
            params["base"] = no_s_characters;
            params["recognize"] = [];
            params["type"] = first_char;

            if is_empty_que and index == 0:
                params["is_correct"] = True \
                    if first_char != "-" and first_char != "+" \
                    else False;
                first_res = params;
                res.append(first_res);
                print(">>> inner loop >>", res);
                continue;
                pass;

            print(per, res,is_empty_que and index == 0);

            last_index_que = res[len(res) - 1];
            last_index = len(res) - 1;

            pass;
```

i want to append if a current item of the loop is `index == 0` and the variable `is_empty_que == True`. the inner loop print is correct it print what the condition should run but on the next loop where `index == 1` and the if `condition == False` the next print should print what the already added item to the variable `res` and i expected the next print will return this

```
{'base': 'a', 'recognize': [], 'type': '-', 'is_correct': False, 'index': 0}
```

but it return

```
{'base': 'b', 'recognize': [], 'type': '+', 'is_correct': False, 'index': 0}
```

to completely...

```
class B(TextBasis):

    @staticmethod
    def check(base):
        attributes = {
            "base" : None,
            "recognize" : None,
            "type" : None,
            "is_correct" : False,
            "index" : 0
        };
        res = [];
        tmp_que = [];
        first_res = None;
        test = False;

        print("_______________________");

        for index,per in enumerate(base):

            no_s_characters = ''.join(e for e in per if e.isalnum());
            first_char = str(per)[0] if len(no_s_characters) > 0 else None;
            is_empty_que = len(res) <= 0;

            params = attributes;
            params["base"] = no_s_characters;
            params["recognize"] = [];
            params["type"] = first_char;

            if is_empty_que and index == 0:
                params["is_correct"] = True \
                    if first_char != "-" and first_char != "+" \
                    else False;
                first_res = params;
                res.append(first_res);
                print(">>> inner loop >>", res);
                continue;
                pass;

            print(per, res,is_empty_que and index == 0);

            last_index_que = res[len(res) - 1];
            last_index = len(res) - 1;

            pass;

        print("______________________")

        pass;

    pass;

y = [["- a", "+ b"]]

for per in y :
    B.check(list(per));
    pass;
```

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI, semicolons aren't necessary in Python, nor is it necessary to put `pass;` at the end of every block.

Comment: `params = attributes` and then `first_res = params` is just creating another variable pointing to the original dict. When the second iteration modifies the dict the reference to it   that has been appended to `res` will reflect the change. You should make copies - `params = attributes.copy()` & `first_res = params.copy()`

Comment: @IainShelvington i dont know about this method  attributes.copy() or copy.deepcopy(attributes) but it works. many thanks :)